# Noun adjuncts (attributive nouns) in the x-bar scheme

Tags: syntax, x-bar-theory

What category are the two nouns for the following phrases:

A) The play by Bill Roberts
B) A chicken soup bowl

according to distributional criteria "Roberts" and "soup" are adjectives, but should they be labeled as such? as heads of an AdjP? if not how can you have two NPs together?

Thank you

Comment: This question is not asking anyone to draw a syntax tree. It is asking about the structure of noun phrases and how attributive modifiers within NP should be labelled (which is just asking what the PoS and functions are). It deserves to be reopened.